# Final property to bind JAXB

Tags: jaxb

I want to implement JAXB for the `Test` class, I find that if variables are `final`, is it not possible to inject JAXB? Will `XmlAdapter` help in this case?

```java
public class Test implements Serializable {
    private final int limit;
    private Map<String, Object> results;
    private final Sub sub;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "item") //tried with this also,but not successfull
    @XmlAnyElement
    private final List<Item> item; 

    public Test(final Sub sub, final List<Item> item, final int limit) {
            this(pattern, results, 0, limit, offset);
    }
}

public class Item implements Serializable {
    private Base base;// Interface

    public Item(final Base base) {
        this.base = base;
    }
}
```

`private final List<Item> item;` is iterating `Item` class which also has an interface `Base`, if I want to implement `xmlAdapter` I need to do it fot `Item` and `Test`?

Comment: The following may help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-immutable-objects.html